ConEmu under Windows 11: specifying different color schemes per instance?
I'm using ConEmu version 230724 under Windows 11.
I'd like to start up separate instances of ConEmu from the command line and be able to specify the color scheme on the command line. By "separate instances", I mean separate ConEmu windows, not separate tabs within the same ConEmu window.
I have created color schemes called "Blue" and "Green" and others via the ConEmu settings.
I'd like to do something like the following in order to choose the scheme that I want ...
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64" -unknownoption "Blue"

... and ...
"C:\Program Files\ConEmu\ConEmu64" -unknownoption "Green"

... etc. ...
... in order to bring up different ConEmu instances with these specified color schemes.
But I haven't been able to find a value for -unknownoption that will work for me.
Is there any way that I can accomplish this?
Thank you in advance for any thoughts and suggestions.
UPDATE: Just for clarification: these ConEmu window colors are not task-specific. In other words, I might want to run a certain ConEmu Task in a "Blue" window and the exact, same ConEmu Task simultaneously in a "Green" window.

How can I specifying different color schemes per instance?
You need to do the following, the steps below are for your "Blue" configuration:

Start ConEmu, apply your chosen color scheme and then save your settings (in ConEmu.xml).
Exit ConEmu, and copy ConEmu.xmlto Blue.xml

Repeat the above for your "Green" configuration (replacing "Blue" with "Green")
Now you can start ConEmu with your chosen colour scheme:
conemu -Config Blue.xml

Or:
conemu -Config Green.xml 


Further Reading

ConEmu | Settings

ConEmu | Settings

ConEmu | ConEmu.exe Command Line Switches



So colors can't be dyamically specified within a given configuration, but multiple configuration files can be specified. Got it! Thank you very much!
